# Edit plotly graph text on hover without modifying data

Tags: python, plotly-python

I'm new to plotly. I'm trying to make values in my graph show as percentages and dates. So far, my markers show like this:

```
(Nov 16, 2022, 80.8)
```

Is there a way to edit the display text so it shows like this (being my columns for Y axis = 'Rate' and X axis = 'Date' ) without having to modify my dataset?

```
Date: Nov, 2022
Rate: 80.8 %
```

I've tried using `hovermode` but I'm still not able to show the Y values as percentages or the X axis as Dates in yyyy/mm.

Comment: Please add minimal code and data to be easier for us to help you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Hamzah! I managed to do it by using the parameter `hovertemplate` in `go.add_trace()` like this:   `hovertemplate='Rate: %{y:.1f}%'+'<br>Date: %{x|%b - %Y}'`